# Icon counter on android

Tags: android, android-layout, icons, notifications

I would like to make an icon counter for Android like this one:

[image]

Does anyone know where to find the UINotofication option to write those numbers in the icon or at least where to find a good tutorial?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do that with a widget. There is no support for icons with counters in the app tray

You can search documentation for help with widget development http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html

Comment: thank you very much. I will try to make it and I'll post the code for everyone :)

Comment: There's a lot of source code around the web for sample widgets like clocks, buttons, etc. Just google it and you'll find it